# Right aligned text block in Org-mode

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Is there are right aligned text block in Org-mode, like `#+begin_center #+end_center`? I haven't been able to find any reference in the official docs. on the other hand, [this page](https://github.com/fniessen/refcard-org-mode) uses a construct `#+begin_right #+end_right` but this doesn't work for me in LaTeX and odt export (see my MWE below and its LaTeX export). Is this type of alignment supported in Org-mode? If it is, how can I set it? If not, would it be a large issue to implement this type of text alignment and exporters?

I'm using Org-mode version 9.1.2 with Emacs 25.3.1.

My MWE is:

```
#+TITLE: Test

* Heading 1

#+begin_right
This text is right-aligned.
#+end_right
```

My LaTeX export is (I've trimmed unnecessary packages and meta-data from the export):

```
% Created 2017-10-11 Wed 11:24
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\section{Heading 1}
\label{sec:orgd88bdfd}

\begin{right}
This text is right-aligned.
\end{right}
\end{document}
```

Edit(): As Simon Fromme suggested in the comments below, I've added my MWE and the output.

Comment: I can't replicate the issue. `#+begin_right #+end_right` works for me with Emacs 25.2.1 and Org-mode 8.2.10 for both HTML and Latex export. Can you provide a minimal example of org-mode Markup and generated HTML/Latex?

Comment: Dear @SimonFromme, I've added the MWE as you've suggested. Unfortunately, my LaTeX won't compile as environment {right} is not defined. I know how to setup this environment but I'm curious if this kind of alignment is officially supported in Org-mode.

Comment: See my answer. There is no such thing as "official support" for this kind of construct.

Comment: It seems that my question was a but vague. I've edited the question a bit and I hope it is a bit clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having an org-mode file with a block of the form

```
#+begin_FOObarBUZZ
some Text
#+end_FOObarBUZZ
```

the Latex exporter seems to wrap anything within the block in a new environment named as the lower case version of `FOObarBUZZ` like:

```
\begin{foobarbuzz}
some Text
\end{foobarbuzz}
```

the HTML exporter behaves similarly and wraps the block within a `div` like:

```
<div class="foobarbuzz">
<p>
some Text
</p>
</div>
```

Nothing smart going on here!

Since `center` happens to be a pre-defined environment in Latex and the CSS class [`center`](https://github.com/jwiegley/org-mode/blob/433103fc5e5bb6d401e37707703a652683b859eb/lisp/ox-html.el#L244) is also part of the [default CSS for HTML export in org-mode](https://github.com/jwiegley/org-mode/blob/433103fc5e5bb6d401e37707703a652683b859eb/lisp/ox-html.el#L232), it naturally works for both Latex and HTML export.

There is no pre-defined `right` environment in Latex, yet there is a CSS class [`right`](https://github.com/jwiegley/org-mode/blob/433103fc5e5bb6d401e37707703a652683b859eb/lisp/ox-html.el#L242) defined in the default CSS for HTML export, so that `#+BEGIN_RIGHT` works only in the latter case given the default org-mode configuration.

Having this said, you could define a new Latex environment `right` that does the alignment and reference this in your org-mode file as described [here](http://orgmode.org/tmp/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-export.html#sec-10).

Comment: Dear @SimonFromme, thank you for the answer. I apologize as my question is a bit vague. This was my temporary solution as well but it is LaTeX specific. I was searching for something that will work for a few exporters I use (namely odt, latex and html), similar to the `#+begin_center #+end_center` block.

Comment: There is no built-in way to do this as the exporters don't treat the string after `#+BEGIN_` in any special way. You can say that `center` (HTML, Latex) and `right` (HTML) only happen to work by chance without further definitions of environments/classes.

Comment: Dear @SimonFromme, thank you for the input and your comment wraps it up. I'll mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

I decided to build on @SimonFromme's excellent answer, and extend it with Org-mode's [ASCII special blocks](https://orgmode.org/manual/ASCII_002fLatin_002d1_002fUTF_002d8-export.html#ASCII-special-blocks) for alignment:

> Besides `#+BEGIN_CENTER` blocks (see [Paragraphs](https://orgmode.org/manual/Paragraphs.html)), ASCII back-end has these two left and right justification blocks:
>
> ```
> #+BEGIN_JUSTIFYLEFT
> It's just a jump to the left...
> #+END_JUSTIFYLEFT
>
> #+BEGIN_JUSTIFYRIGHT
> ...and then a step to the right.
> #+END_JUSTIFYRIGHT
> ```

Since they're also exported to LaTeX as `JUSTIFYRIGHT` or `JUSTIFYLEFT` environments (and to HTML as div elements with similarly named class attributes), one could also integrate this for LaTeX export as:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{ragged2e}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newenvironment{JUSTIFYLEFT}{\begin{FlushLeft}}{\end{FlushLeft}}
#+LATEX_HEADER: \newenvironment{JUSTIFYRIGHT}{\begin{FlushRight}}{\end{FlushRight}}
```

And for HTML export with:

```
#+HTML_HEAD: <style>.JUSTIFYLEFT {text-align: left;}</style>
#+HTML_HEAD: <style>.JUSTIFYRIGHT {text-align: right;}</style>
```

So, the previous org markup quoted would be exported to the following when exporting to LaTeX:

> ```
> \begin{JUSTIFYLEFT}
> It's just a jump to the left...
> \end{JUSTIFYLEFT}
>
> \begin{JUSTIFYRIGHT}
> ...and then a step to the right.
> \end{JUSTIFYRIGHT}
> ```

And to the following when exporting to HTML:

> ```
> <div class="JUSTIFYLEFT" id="org0a1b2c3">
> <p>
> It&rsquo;s just a jump to the left&#x2026;
> </p>
>
> </div>
>
> <div class="JUSTIFYRIGHT" id="org4d5e6f7">
> <p>
> &#x2026;and then a step to the right.
> </p>
>
> </div>
> ```

And, to the following when exporting to ASCII / UTF-8:

> ```
> It's just a jump to the left...
>
>                   ...and then a step to the right.
> ```

*Note*: The link from @SimonFromme's answer for the [custom environment definition for Block-level markup](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-latex-export.html#org86d7713) has moved.